# Translating python subprocess to Java Process

Tags: java, python, subprocess

I need to execute a shell command through Java, but something wrong with my Java code.

Actually, I can run the cmd through java.

The whole command line is "solc-0.4.25 --bin /Users/programmerc/Documents/Research_Data/Smart_Contract_Source_Code/SourceCode/0xb7b80925d8e86b787ff21f96112c588aa6bb32a9.sol | solc-0.4.25 --link --libraries /Users/programmerc/Documents/Researc:0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001"

It is normal with my python code. The code is:

```
option = "--libraries /Users/programmerc/Documents/Researc:0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001"
FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
cmd = "solc-0.4.25 --bin-runtime %s" % filename
p1 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=FNULL)
cmd = "solc-0.4.25 --link%s" %option
p2 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=FNULL)
p1.stdout.close()
out = p2.communicate()[0].decode()
```

However, there is something wrong with my Java code. My Java code is:

```
    public static String runCMDWithTimeout(String cmd[]){

        final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        String result = null;
        Callable<String> call = new Callable<String>() {
            public String call() throws Exception {
                String result = "";
                Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

                InputStream in = null;
                in = pro.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line = "";
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    result += line + "\n";
                pro.destroy();
                return result;
            }
        };

        try {

            Future<String> future = exec.submit(call);
            result = future.get(1000 * 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        } catch (TimeoutException e){
            System.out.println(cmd[cmd.length-1] + " ===> time out");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            exec.shutdown();
        }

        return result;
    }

    String str = "solc-0.4.25 --bin /Users/programmerc/Documents/Research_Data/Smart_Contract_Source_Code/SourceCode/0xb7b80925d8e86b787ff21f96112c588aa6bb32a9.sol | solc-0.4.25 --link --libraries /Users/programmerc/Documents/Researc:0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001";
  
    String output = Utils.runCMDWithTimeout(str.splite(" "));
```

I have try the code, but I return nothing.

Comment: Hi, people in SO wont do the job for you. Show some good faith, try to do it by yourself and when you encounter a problem with your java code come back, we will gladly help you :)

Comment: Many thanks for your remind. Actually, I have my Java Code, but it cannot work normally. I have changed my question, and added the java code

Comment: Is there any error showing on your console ? Why do you split your string instead of passing the whole command to `exec` ? `splite` doesn't exist in java so this sample of code won't compile.